# Как из стандартного календаря showDatePicker Flutter при выборе даты переходить в ListView.builder на конкретную страницу с датой?

Tags: flutter

Ребята привет, помогите решить задачку. Как из стандартного календаря showDatePicker Flutter при выборе даты переходить в ListView.builder на конкретную страницу с датой?

````
onTap: () {
       showDatePicker(
         context: context,
         initialDate: DateTime.now(),
         firstDate: DateTime(2021),
         lastDate: DateTime(2023),
         builder: (BuildContext context, child) {
           return Theme(
             data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
               colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                 primary: Colors.white,
                 onPrimary: COLOR_BG_MENU,
                 surface: COLOR_BG_MENU,
                 onSurface: Colors.white,
               ),
               dialogBackgroundColor: COLOR_BG_END,
             ),
             child: child!,
           );
         },
       ).then((date) {
         Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/day');
         //setState((){})
       });
     },
// day_list.dart    
ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
         itemCount: DAY_DATA.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return LunarDayItem(
             itemData: DAY_DATA[index],
           );
   
// day_data.dart    
const DAY_DATA = [
 {
   "image": "assets/images/day_1.png",
   "day": "1 Day",
 },
  {
   "image": "assets/images/day_2.png",
   "day": "2 Day",
 },
  {
   "image": "assets/images/day_3.png",
   "day": "3 Day",
 },
  {
   "image": "assets/images/day_4.png",
   "day": "4 Day",
 },
  {
   "image": "assets/images/day_5.png",
   "day": "5 Day",
 },
];  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял
В pushNamed можно передать дату как аргумент и уже на странице принять дату и отобразить то, что вам нужно
Делается это примерно так

```dart
var date = 'date';

Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/day',
    arguments: {'date': date},
);
```

Вытаскиваем подобным образом

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;

    if (arguments != null) print(arguments['exampleArgument']);

    return Scaffold(...);
}
```